# Is it possible to write this javascript array declaration shorter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to write this "singleton array declaration" even shorter? There are different scripts which adds something to `array` but they're loaded asynchronously, so I don't know which will initialize `array` first.

```
var array = array || [];
    array.push("foo");

console.debug(array[0]);
```

I tried something like this but this doesn't work:

```
(array || []).push("foo");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `(typeof array == 'undefined')?array = ['foo']:array.push('foo');`

Comment: You are already there, `var array = array || [];array.push("foo");` is the best.

Comment: this should probably be in code golf ;)

Comment: Ok I thought there is something like `(array || []) += "value"`, maybe to groovy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to preserve the existing variable (which would happen if you don't know which piece of code will execute first), your code can't be written any shorter.

Of course, you can change the default value if you want:

```
var array = array || ['foo'];
```

But if the variable already exists, it won't add `foo` anymore. Probably not what you want.

**Old answer**

With your given example:

```
var array = ['foo'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [];
array.push("foo");

console.debug(array[0]);
```

If you're not adding elements dynamically, than this is enough:

```
var array = ["foo"];
console.debug(array[0]);
```

Update:

Again, if you know your elements upfront, do

```
 var array = array || ['foo']
```

Comment: Uhm, but another declaration of `var array = [];` overvwrites the variable? Also I'm adding elements dynamically.

Comment: but he can have it initialized to different values if array was defined before

Comment: @soulcheck - if OP wants to use an existing array, just `push` will be enough.

Comment: Ok, that's not what I want, there are different scripts which adds something to `array` but they're loaded asynchronous, so I don't know which will initialize `array` first. Sorry for not mentioning this in the main post

Comment: @JakubKonecki he doesn't need to know if there's an existing array. That's what `array || []` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want with the `array || []`. But this is how you get the same:

```
var array = new Array("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is to check if array is already defined when you try to push:

```
var array = ​typeof array === 'undefined' ? ['foo'] : array.push('foo');​​​​​​​​​​
```

For readability's sake, you may want to create a lazy-loaded getter:

```
var addToArray = function (item) {
    // ensure array is defined
    if (typeof array === 'undefined') {
        array = [].push(item);
    }

    // redefine this function as a reference to push
    addToArray = array.push;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the bracket notation since its faster then using new Array().
If you need to add items dynamically, you'll need to use .push(); - or take care of the numeric index of your array by yourself.

Ok, didn't read your comment above about async loaded scripts. Why don't you just declare your array before any of the other scripts are loaded, so you can be sure that your array exists?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to affect the array passed in

```
var newVals = (vals || []).concat(["c","d"]);
```

or

```
var newVals = [].concat((vals || []), ["c","d"]);
```